# Inserting a node into a linked list C using trailing pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a linked list of names in alphabetical order, I've noticed this is a semi common problem, but I'm having a little difficulty with the implementation.

So, the way I see it is, the item can be added at the beginning, middle or end of a linked list, I think I'm struggling with adding it in at the end.

Here is my implementation of a boolean:

```
typedef int bool;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

Here is my node/item/struct:

```
typedef struct student_s Student;

struct student_s {
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    int age;
    Student* next;              // Pointer to next student in a list
};
```

My compare function:

```
// Compares two student structs based on their name and age, and returns true
// if student1 should come before student2 in alphabetical order
bool comesBefore(const Student* student1, const Student* student2) {
    int name_compare = strcmp(student1->name, student2->name);

    if (name_compare < 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else if (name_compare == 0) {
        int age1 = student1->age;
        int age2 = student2->age;
        if (age1 < age2) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

My insert function:

```
Student* insert(Student* student, Student* list) {
    Student* curr = NULL;
    Student* prev = NULL;
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("list == null\n");
        return student;
    }
    if (comesBefore(student, list)) {
        printf("Student comes before list\n");
        printf("Student age = %d\n", student->age);
        printf("List age = %d\n", list->age);
        student->next = list;
        return student;
    }
    for (curr = list, prev = NULL; curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, 
        curr) != TRUE; prev = curr, curr = curr->next) {
        printf("Stage 1\n\n");
        printf("curr age = %d\n", curr->age);
        printf("student age = %d\n", student->age);
        if (comesBefore(student, curr)) {
            printf("Stage 2\n");
            if (prev != NULL) {
                prev->next = student;
            }
            student->next = curr;
            break;
        }
        if ((curr->next) == NULL) {
            printf("Appended at the end of the list\n");
            curr->next = student;
            break;
        }       
    }
    return list; 

}
```

And my main function with all the testing:

```
int main(void)
{
    Student* student1 = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    Student* student2 = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    Student* student3 = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    strncpy(student1->name, "AAAAA", MAX_NAME_SIZE);
    student1->age = 10;
    student1->next = NULL;
    student2->next = NULL;
    student3->next = NULL;
    strncpy((*student2).name, "BBBBB", MAX_NAME_SIZE);
    (*student2).age = 100;
    strncpy((*student3).name, "CCCC", MAX_NAME_SIZE);
    (*student3).age = 1000;
    Student* list1 = insert(student1, NULL);
    Student* list2 = insert(student3, list1);
    Student* list3 = insert(student2, list2);
    printf("head %d\n", list3->age);
    printf("second element %d\n", (list3->next)->age);
    printf("third element %d\n", ((list3->next)->next)->age);
}
```

Problem is I keep getting a segmentation fault. I think it's when I try to access the next node in the list (curr->next) when next is set to NULL, but for whatever reason my if statement

```
    if ((curr->next) == NULL) {
        printf("Appended at the end of the list\n");
        curr->next = student;
        break;
    }
```

Is never being triggered. Why? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: What is value of `MAX_NAME_SIZE`?

Comment: Sidenote: you should not implement your own `bool`, if your compiler supports `stdbool.h`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because standard DCV 'cos LL questions with no debugging done.

Comment: MAX_NAME_SIZE is 50 or so, definitely long enough for the strings I used.

Didn't realize, user694733, thanks!

Martin, sorry to be a complete novice, but how would I go about debugging... sorry.

Comment: why won't you try debuging the insert function with gdb?

Comment: @Jite How is that any different? `!FALSE` expands to `!0` which is `1`. If you just stick to the interface and don't mix integers with booleans, you're good. [`stdbool.h`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdbool_8h_source.html) defines `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0` too.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Brainfart. I mixed it up with potential type problems. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your insert function doesn't really insert in the general case. Look at the loop body:

```
for (curr = list, prev = NULL; curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, 
    curr) != TRUE; prev = curr, curr = curr->next) {
    printf("Stage 1\n\n");
    printf("curr age = %d\n", curr->age);
    printf("student age = %d\n", student->age);
    if (comesBefore(student, curr)) {
        printf("Stage 2\n");
        if (prev != NULL) {
            prev->next = student;
        }
        student->next = curr;
        break;
    }
    if ((curr->next) == NULL) {
        printf("Appended at the end of the list\n");
        curr->next = student;
        break;
    }       
}
```

The loop body is entered only if `curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, curr) != TRUE`, so `if (comesBefore(student, curr))` will never be true inside the loop.

Instead, you want to insert once the loop terminates, i.e., *after* the loop. You also don't need that `if ((curr->next) == NULL)` inside the loop; if that is true, then the loop will iterate one more time, `curr` will be `NULL` and `prev` will be the pointer you're interested in. The loop condition is well written, you're just doing things in the wrong place.

This will work:

```
for (curr = list, prev = NULL;
     curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, curr) != TRUE;
     prev = curr, curr = curr->next) {
    printf("Stage 1\n\n");
    printf("curr age = %d\n", curr->age);
    printf("student age = %d\n", student->age);
}

student->next = curr;
prev->next = student;

return list;
```

Here's the entire function with this fix:

```
Student* insert(Student* student, Student* list) {
    Student* curr = NULL;
    Student* prev = NULL;
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("list == null\n");
        return student;
    }
    if (comesBefore(student, list)) {
        printf("Student comes before list\n");
        printf("Student age = %d\n", student->age);
        printf("List age = %d\n", list->age);
        student->next = list;
        return student;
    }
    for (curr = list, prev = NULL;
         curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, curr) != TRUE;
         prev = curr, curr = curr->next) {
        printf("Stage 1\n\n");
        printf("curr age = %d\n", curr->age);
        printf("student age = %d\n", student->age);
    }

    student->next = curr;
    prev->next = student;

    return list;
}
```

When you're done debugging, the loop body will be empty; you might want to add a comment saying this is intentional (I usually like to do this so that other people reading the code know that it's not a bug). Something like:

```
Student* insert(Student* student, Student* list) {
    Student* curr = NULL;
    Student* prev = NULL;
    if (list == NULL)
        return student;

    if (comesBefore(student, list)) {
        student->next = list;
        return student;
    }

    for (curr = list, prev = NULL;
         curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, curr) != TRUE;
         prev = curr, curr = curr->next)
        ; /* Intentionally left blank */

    student->next = curr;
    prev->next = student;

    return list;
}
```

Also, you don't need to test for `prev != NULL`, because if the loop is reached, then we know that `comesBefore(student, list)` is false (because we test this earlier in the code), so the loop will always execute at least once. For self-documentation (and to ensure that this variant is not violated with future code changes), you might want to add an `assert(3)` after the loop, like so:

```
Student* insert(Student* student, Student* list) {
    Student* curr = NULL;
    Student* prev = NULL;
    if (list == NULL)
        return student;

    if (comesBefore(student, list)) {
        student->next = list;
        return student;
    }

    for (curr = list, prev = NULL;
         curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, curr) != TRUE;
         prev = curr, curr = curr->next)
        ; /* Intentionally left blank */

    assert(prev != NULL);

    student->next = curr;
    prev->next = student;

    return list;
}
```

You need to `#include <assert.h>` to use `assert(3)`.